# Detecting a type from a partial of a discriminated unions in typescript

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm having an issue making a type detecting function that takes a partial amount of fields from a discriminated union and returns the matching type from the union. I have a `create()` function that takes fields excluding timestamps and an ID and I return those fields with an ID and timestamps. We have the `type` field in the argument and the return object but it's not being used to determine the return type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmKDeAoZZMATwAcIAuZAZzClAHMDlhMrb6QnCEoI5ImAIJgqIAK4BbAEbRm40pgERho5BJlyAvnjyhIsRCgAK6ANYRJ6EMggAPSCEzU0WXMxLkqAclMWrIN7MIHCSlDR0jADceDp64NDwSMgAKlBwoNC2DhBOLhjYyPiEnuHeaRkg0EGEIWHskVwxhKTmltYNnAwA2gC6sbp4pcgAwnzKBRAAPCnZjs6u2AB8yAC8qXO5C+IgZiDoAO4gzIQA-MgA8pLAYDMANMjerN7IAD6PvPyCIi-v3gpKb5gbxLE7IMQQABucjwMB2CDAwGsyE+yimACVNnlFhAlgAKdDSABWVDGXwgkwxSwAlFRMcVkHwwOIoDYGYQAHRcwlEu5g1g+ZzePmEHjjIFUAAsItFAOUqioAFYZVpkAB6NXIBjAaHIOAuaBQdBQZAAIi5HL1LmALn11GADBC0gANigwOgiAALFAIawcSpgZDoGBEMgobzo4XIaTiQMRl6+8TOzDRlCgWhwcDAeXIA43T165CYYAwGDQXKB6jiaTDYMov10AOPSbeDmmgZ4X0gWjIVr+ZHrVGQKZ+dogV4VTJQfEM0o+UcBYXBUJlADicHSzrgdjgrUCsWpulKdb7Y-VauonvQSZTsmQC+RMcDNvvbQCb1S6SnQA)

```js
interface Node {
  type: string
  id: string
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
}

interface Pokemon extends Node {
  type: 'Pokemon'
  name: string;
}

interface Trainer extends Node {
  type: 'Trainer'
  name: string;
  pokemon: string[]
}


type CreateNode<T extends Node> = T extends unknown
    ? Omit<T, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'>
    : never

function create<R extends Node>(obj: CreateNode<R>): R {
  return {
    ...obj,
    id: 'ds',
    createdAt: 4,
    updatedAt: 5,
  } // give as error "... as is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Node'."
}

const pokemon = create<Pokemon|Trainer>({
  type: 'Pokemon',
  name: 'Garalaxapon'
})

pokemon //should be Pokemon but is Pokemon | Trainer
```

I don't understand the error in the return but I'm sure that's the crux of it. Thank you!

Comment: The error inside the implementation has nothing to do with the issue you're seeing when calling it.  You could write `declare function create<R extends Node>(obj: CreateNode<R>): R;` and have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the issue inside the implementation, which is a separate problem from the one you're asking about. For now I will assume that the implementation works, and use a [`declare` statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-functions) to focus on just the call signature issue.

---

The problem you're facing is that you are expecting too much from the single `R` generic type.  You are specifying it manually to let the compiler know which particular union of `Node` subtypes you want to discriminate.  But then you also want the compiler to somehow narrow `R` to one of the members of that union.  This doesn't work.  Once you manually specify `R` as a union, it's that union forever.

You could potentially solve this with two generic parameters; one (`R`) you specify for the discriminated union, and one (`T`) the compiler infers from the passed-in parameter.  Unfortunately you can't do this in a single function signature; either you need to manually specify both `R` and `T`, or the compiler will try to infer both `R` and `T`.  There's no [partial type parameter inference (microsoft/TypeScript#26242)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) in TypeScript.

Sometimes in situations like this I use type parameter [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to split the single function of two type parameters into multiple one-type-parameter functions.  In your case it would look like this:

```
declare function create<R extends Node>(): <T extends CreateNode<R>>(obj: T) => Extract<R, T>;
```

Note how `R` corresponds to the full discriminated union, while `T` refers to the type of the passed-in `obj` parameter.  You discriminate `R` with `T` by using the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type: return only the elements of `R` which are assignable to `T`:

```
const createPokemonOrTrainer = create<Pokemon | Trainer>();

const pokemon = createPokemonOrTrainer({
  type: 'Pokemon',
  name: 'Garalaxapon'
}); // Pokemon
```

Here, `create()` returns another function, and `create<Pokemon | Trainer>()` returns the function you were trying to make before: something that accepts a partial-ish `Pokemon | Trainer` and discriminates it to just `Pokemon` or `Trainer`.

---

But maybe you don't actually even need `R` at all here; are you planning to call `create()` with a different discriminated union each time?  If you're only ever going to use a single union type like `Pokemon | Trainer`, then you can just hardcode it.  Essentially, don't bother with the over-generic `create()` and just manually write `createPokemonOrTrainer()`:

```
type DiscrimUnion = Pokemon | Trainer;
declare function createDiscrimUnion<T extends CreateNode<DiscrimUnion>>(obj: T): Extract<DiscrimUnion, T>;

const pokemonAlso = createDiscrimUnion({
  type: 'Pokemon',
  name: 'Garalaxapon'
}); // Pokemon
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A1iAnkg3gKCSVElgWQGEB7SFAOVzwMKQEtgAXCAJwDMylalACbJ8zZu0wwIALiRR2XNgHMm4lkLkKlwVeMLwuEEJyEBBdnOABXMACNua5tZhCTEc5aK2HXJwF9GdQ5uPkQkAAVKNAgwSmAkCAAPTmAhKAFhUSdCSWk5AHIomLjgApyicFl5RRUAbgCg5jZOXn4AFS4QNm5ElIg0jMERBn0kPOqCzu7gbnKx4mrteoqYaNj4rVrdAG0AXQCkRicJpHIjd2GIAB52vtT0zJEAPiQAXiQ75IeM62A0YCUADuwAqAH5UGAWOxbgAaJAFDQFJAAHwRhmMpgsyLRBRcbix7AKzwqVggADdHE4RPAADYgIxIHh-eDsFjxJAY9zXABK9wGjyuzwAFABKOS3fmDM4XThXXnPEWUOwAKzk7VF71eAFEUl1Wbz4e1ng0nPB4gpObKIMUNsAUFxpj0uO8rZibrbSqjPl1nSLRabxObgJa1iUOR8uZxPfEHU7ZlxhWJ9BNCjGyrCKotCgBxBkgelJEBrMoBANIAD0Fci61KTVyUmQABEWFBDCwwABVYDshIfdPe+PcBriGn0xnM4Cs3tu9wtttKLs9+KS74CjLnd3y+ftpe9xXC5Vqz7ipC6xQIGE7xfd3tGk31zkW9hIMN2sy0qCUV1RiDXju3vESYVKmCLpgUmYLFUub5oWxbxPMzD+OWVY1uGoJMIEgRAA)

Comment: oh you're spot on, instead of two functions I'm using a class that takes the union and `create()` is a method. This is closer to what I'm actually building https://tsplay.dev/Bmx5KW

Comment: This works, but I don't yet understand how. Since T is an extension of CreateNode<DiscrimUnion> Then.. How on earth does extract find the right object? Since T is a subset of fields of anything possible in DiscrimUnion

Comment: Proof it's working for me https://tsplay.dev/AwQK7m I noticed some type inference gotchas that aren't super ergonomic but this is fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> `pokemon //should be Pokemon but is Pokemon | Trainer`

This is correct. Reason:

You have `const pokemon = create<Pokemon|Trainer>` where `create<R extends Node>(obj: CreateNode<R>): R`. Since `create` returns the `R` that is passed in, pokemon will be the `R` that you are passing in. You are passing in `Pokemon|Trainer` So `pokemon: Pokemon|Trainer`

## Solution

Use `Pokemon` if that is what you want i.e. `create<Pokemon>`

Comment: My code up there is a simplified of the full use case where an object is created with the union and create is function on that object. While what your saying still mostly applies (I'm unsure if the types will be easily available where this code is called in production) I feel like there's probably a way to make this work and the DX would be fantastic.

Comment: This is closer to what I'm actually building https://tsplay.dev/Bmx5KW and figure the Client class is constructed far away from the developer using the class.